# Printing 2d Array with unknown number of strings in C

Tags: arrays, c

I have written a small program to read in a series of strings from a file and then to store them in a 2D Arrray. The strings are read into the array correctly, yet my program is not countering the number of rows in the file like I had expected.

I am honestly at a loss and cannot figure out why the program is not counting the rows in the file. Any explanation as to what I am doing wrong is greatly appreciated.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE* fp;
    char nameArray[20][120], str[20];
    int i = 0, j = 0, n;
    int count = 0;
    char name[20]; //filename
    int ch;

    printf("Please enter a file name: ");
    scanf("%s", &name);

    fp = fopen(name, "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("File \"%s\" does not exist!\n", name);
        return -1;
    }

    while (fscanf(fp, "%s", str) != EOF)
    {
        strcpy(nameArray[i], str);
        i++;
    }

    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if (ch == '\n')
            count++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i<=count; i++)
    {
        printf("%s", nameArray[i]);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you don't start counting until you are already at the end of the file.  If you want to go thru twice, you need to rewind.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have done when you recommended. Now it does count the rows in the file, but not it is not reading the file into the 2d array.

Comment: _yet my program is not countering the number of rows in the file_, what do you mean by **number of  rows**, if row is a line, then where are you checking for `\n`(line end)

Comment: Also note that turning off warnings is like taking the batteries out of your smoke detector when your house is on fire.